# How to structure this HTML to center stuff in a div

Tags: html, css

Sometimes when I come back to html I forget the simple things...

I want to be able to get the spans inside the div to center. IDK if I have it structured right, feel free to suggest anything

https://jsfiddle.net/yxg1zsac/

```css
    .define_link {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding: 5px;
        width: 200px;
        margin: 5px auto;
        font-size: 20px;
        display: inline-block;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .pagination {
     width:100%;
     margin:auto
    }
```

```html
    <div class="pagination">
        <span class="define_link"><a href="">previous</a></span>
        <span class="current">Page 2 of 88.</span>
        <span class="define_link"><a href=""></a>next</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: they do center, just not at every browser width. what are you looking to happen once the page size becomes too small?

Comment: the spans are not centered for me...all three of them are aligned on the left

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

https://jsfiddle.net/tobyl/yxg1zsac/1/

Critical CSS:

```
.pagination {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: thanks I knew it was something simple. I just can't think in html after I have been doing a lot of other stuff

Comment: Happens to me all the time.  :)  If this answer helped, I'd appreciate if you could mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

i think you want to this check it 
https://jsfiddle.net/bhavhirani/gnrqxxka/1/

```css
.define_link {
   background: rgba(0,0,0,.3);
   border-radius: 10px;
   padding: 5px;
   width: 200px;
   margin: 5px auto;
   font-size: 20px;
   display: inline-block;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-align: center;
}
.define_link.prev{ 
   float:left;
 }
.current { 
  display: block; float: left; width: 30%; margin: 10px auto; text-align: center; 
}
.define_link.next{
 float:right; 
}
.pagination { 
   width:100%; 
   margin:auto; 
}
```

```html
<div class="pagination">
    <span class="define_link prev"><a href="">previous</a></span>
    <span class="current">Page 2 of 88.</span>
    <span class="define_link next"><a href=""></a>next</span>
</div>
```

Comment: try This i think is ok for You..!